# How do I select first child of an array in a object?

Tags: arrays

How do I iterate over the first element(question) of each science object/array? I use "science.question" that's not working.
```

```
var scienceQuestion = {
  scienceQue: function(){
    for (var i = 0; i <science.question.length; i++)
    science.question = questionsDiv.innerHtml
  },
science: [
  { question: "What size is",
    choices: [10,44,15],
    correctIndex: 1
  },

  { question: "???",
    choices: [0,1,2],
    correctIndex: 2
  }

]
}
```

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect your code to look something more like this...

```
var scienceQuestion = {
scienceQue: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.science.length; i++) {
        questionsDiv.innerHTML += this.science[i].question;
    }
},
science: [
    { question: "What size is", choices: [10, 44, 15], correctIndex: 1 },
    { question: "???", choices: [0, 1, 2], correctIndex: 2 }
]
}
```

The way you have defined your scienceQuestion object, science is a property of it and is an array. Therefore, you need to use this within the scienceQuestion object to refer to it e.g. this.science. And as it is an array, you need to use this.science[0], etc to refer to the array's elements. If you need to iterate over them, then use a for loop and this.science[i] to get each element in the loop up to this.science.length, as above. My example merely appends to a div element's innerHTML property, so that you can see the result. Hope that helps :)